# Assign Value to R sparse-Matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

Assigning a value to a column of a sparse matrix using the most straight forward syntax `M[,1] <- 0` is surprisingly slow in R. Following https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-December/262365.html's advice, I tried to nullify the column from the dense storage encoding of the matrix (see nullify.column function), but turned out to even slower in some cases, faster in others, depending on the number of non-zero values in the column to nullify:

```
library(Matrix)

nullify.column <- function(M, i) {
  M.dense <- summary(M)
  filter <- M.dense$j!=i
  return(sparseMatrix(i=M.dense$i[filter], j=M.dense$j[filter], x=M.dense$x[filter]))
}

build.random.sparse.matrix <- function(n,p,q) {
  i <- sample(x = 1:n, replace = T, size = q)
  j <- sample(x = 1:p, replace = T, size = q)
  s <- rnorm(q)^2
  M <- sparseMatrix(i,j,x = s)
  return(M)
}

t0 <- Sys.time()

n <- 1000000
p <- 50000
sparse.ratio <- 0.001
q <- n*p * sparse.ratio
t1 <- Sys.time()
A <- build.random.sparse.matrix(n,p,q)
B <- build.random.sparse.matrix(n,1,q*2) # column to nullify with more non-zero-values
M <- cbind(B,A)
t2 <- Sys.time()
delta <- round(as.numeric(difftime(t2,t1,units="secs")),2)
print(paste(c("Building sparse matrix took ", delta, "s"), collapse=""))

t1 <- Sys.time()
M.bis <- nullify.column(M,1)
t2 <- Sys.time()
delta <- round(as.numeric(difftime(t2,t1,units="secs")),2)
print(paste(c("nullify.column took ", delta, "s"), collapse=""))

t1 <- Sys.time()
M[,1] <- 0
t2 <- Sys.time()
delta <- round(as.numeric(difftime(t2,t1,units="secs")),2)
print(paste(c( "M[,i] <- 0 took ", delta, "s"), collapse=""))

t3 <- Sys.time()
delta <- round(as.numeric(difftime(t3,t0,units="secs")),2)
print(paste(c( "overall time ", delta, "s"), collapse=""))
```

returns

```
[1] "Building sparse matrix took 58.86s"
[1] "nullify.column took 31.2s"
[1] "M[,i] <- 0 took 186.55s"
[1] "overall time 278.49s"
```

**Any idea?** This `M[,1] <- 0` takes longer than advanced SVD algorithms and is ruining my overall performances.

**UPDATE**

just to check I, tried the following code

```
# test 2
M <- cbind(B,A)
N <- t(M)

t1 <- Sys.time()
N[1,] <- 0
t2 <- Sys.time()
delta <- round(as.numeric(difftime(t2,t1,units="secs")),2)
print(paste(c( "t(M)[,i] <- 0 took ", delta, "s"), collapse=""))
```

that returned

```
[1] "t(M)[,i] <- 0 took 2.05s"
```

It seems that sparse matrices are row oriented rather than column oriented, and it is much faster to nullify a row than a column.

Comment: "It seems that sparse matrices are row oriented rather than column oriented": No, Matrix offers both, but by default `sparseMatrix` returns a CsparseMatrix.